# Eclipse breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I have a java application, and to execute all the code to the first breakpoint takes about 2 hours.
Is there a way to restart from that point of breakpoints without waiting another two hours?

Comment: Hotspot allows hot code replacement, also you can [drop to  strackframe](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-droptoframe.htm). You can also select a stackframe in the stack view of the debugger.

Comment: I am really concerning about what code is that which taking almost 2 hrs..  :O so whats the duration of complete execution cycle then?

Comment: Do you need 2 hours because, you have to step 1000times throug a loop, or does the usual execution without any breakpoints take 2 hours?

Comment: That’s what unit testing was invented for…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by active breakpoints, your code runs slowly. you should enable only this breakpoint or you can use a code like unit tests to run your codes part.